# Lambda Function Alias is having more than 1 versions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, lambda, aws-cdk

I am trying to deploy a CDK stack which creates a Lambda function. It was working as expected, but now the deployment is failing with the error `InvalidParameterValueException: Additional version weight must be less than 100 %`.
I have tried to manually edit the lambda alias configuration to not have additional alias using console, but it is not getting updated.
Is there a way by which we can make sure that the Lambda alias always has only one version and it points to the latest version? Manual updates through console are not working.

Also, tried to delete and redeploy the entire stack. But it is still failing with the same error.

Comment: Add the relevant CDK code to the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.